# How to change button from toggle to single-state?

Tags: html, css, angular

I added a button to my project. It is a plain-vanilla button, i.e.:
   `<button (click)="doSomething()">Do Something</button>`

But unfortunately, for some reason it's acting sort of like a toggle button, except that once it's pressed, it stays pressed (even on subsequent clicks), rather than popping back to the pre-pressed state.  I checked the `styles.css` and there's no special styling for buttons there aside from `button.calendar` styling, and I don't believe my project has any other styling for buttons in other locations.

It becomes "pressed" after it's been clicked and it still has focus. When it loses focus, then it pops back up. I'd like it to pop back to its initial state as soon as it's pressed, whether it has focus or not.

Any ideas how I can make it a "regular", plain-vanilla, "one-state" button? Many thanks!

(In case it's useful, here is the code for `doSomething` . . . actually called `addRow()` in my code . . . ):

```
 addRow(targetKey: string) {
    let maxRecs;
    let newRow;
    let thisType: Type<any>;

      switch (targetKey) {
        case "email":
          newRow = new EmailRowData(++this.maxIds[targetKey]).email;
          maxRecs = this.maxEmails;
        break;
        case "phone":
          newRow = new PhoneRowData(++this.maxIds[targetKey]).phone;
          maxRecs = this.maxPhones;
        break
      }
      thisType = SubEnrollFormRowComponent;
      this.member[targetKey].rowData[this.member[targetKey].rowData.length]=newRow;

    }
```

. . . and here is the HTML that contains the button

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="member[key].catText.repeats">
      <button type="button" (click)="addRow(key)">+</button>
  </ng-container> 
  <ng-container *ngFor="let rw of rowArray; index as i">
    <app-sub-enroll-form-row 
      [inputFields]="rw"
      [idx]="i"
      [repeatSec]="repeatSec"
      [maxIds]="maxIds" 
      [numCols]="numCols" 
      [formGroup]="form" 
      [form]="form"
      (delEvent)="hideRow($event)"></app-sub-enroll-form-row>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: What is the code for `doSomething`? It may be affecting the button state.

Comment: what do you mean by while it still has focus? it probably has :hover property or a :focus property.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example  ?

Comment: I created a Stackblitz example with the same code, but the behavior was normal (i.e. as desired/expected) so I couldn't replicate the problem. The Stackblitz `styles.css` file is empty, and I couldn't see anywhere else that the `button` would get its formatting. Aside from `styles.css`, component `.css` files or inline styling, is there anywhere else that an element would get styling from? Could some of a file's imports provide some "hidden" styling?

Comment: The button that has unexpected behavior is in a project that imports some third-party libraries, but I assumed that if those libraries don't affect `styles.css` or other `.css` files in my project, that they wouldn't explain the strange behavior. Is my assumption valid, or could those libraries have "hidden" `.css` files that could affect my button styling? If so, how would I examine/override such "hidden" styling?

Comment: Strangely, I was able to "override" the unwanted behavior using inline styling, but changes in my `styles.css` file did not override the problematic behavior. Why wouldn't changes in the `styles.css` have any effect? No other `.css` file that I can see in the explorer has any styling for buttons, nor was there any inline button styling previously. Many thanks if any explanations!